# React HOC with multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a React HOC that would ideally receive two components instead of one wrapped component and toggle between them. That is, in the code below, instead of `<h3>component one</h3>` and `<h3>component two<h3>`, they would each represent child components. How would I be able to accomplish this? Some psuedo code for how I would write this HOC:

```
<HOC>
  <ComponentOne />
  <ComponentTwo />
</HOC>

<HOC
  componentOne={<ComponentOne />}
  componentTwo={<ComponentTwo />}
/>

hoc(componentOne, componentTwo)
```

```js
class HOC extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      onClick: false,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({onClick: !this.state.onClick});
  }
    

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me!</button>
        { 
          this.state.onClick ?
            <h3>component one</h3> :
            <h3>component two</h3>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<HOC />, app);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a component has more than one child then `this.props.children` will be an array.

```
class HOC extends React.Component {

    // ... rest of code ....

    render() {
        const { onClick } = this.state;
        const { children } = this.props;

        return !onClick ? children[0] : children[1];
    }
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
<HOC>
    <div>Child One</div>   
    <div>Child Two</div>
</HOC>
```

Obviously this will only work with two children but you could extend it by passing an integer to `<HOC>` through props to tell it what child to select.

### Edit

After a quick look at the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#react.children) this is a better version of what I wrote above as `this.props.children` is not an array, it is an opaque data structure:

```
class HOC extends React.Component {

    // ... rest of code ...

    render() {
        const { onClick } = this.state;
        const children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);

        return !onClick ? children[0] : children[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understood you. Why do you need it to be HOC?

If you would pass components as props like that:

```
<HOC
  componentOne={<ComponentOne />}
  componentTwo={<ComponentTwo />}
/>
```

Then you would be able to access them using props.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me!</button>
        { 
          this.state.onClick ?
            this.props.componentOne :
            this.props.componentTwo
        }
      </div>
    );
   }
```

Comment: Yes, essentially this. I am just wondering, is this the most elegant way to pass and handle multiple components in another component? Obviously with React HOC and `this.props.children` there are ways of rendering child props / components, but you aren't really able to use those tools when having to logically handle multiple child components.

Comment: a bit confused... would you like to pass more then two components?